# How to make a variable which consists of multiple 'divs'

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a question regarding variables in Javascript.

When I assign a var to a ID I do it like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("div_name");
```

But I would like to make a variable which consists of multiple 'divs'.

I thought this might work but I does not:

```
var x = document.getElementById("div_name"),document.getElementById("div_name2");
```

Can someone please help me find the right code syntax and explain why the syntax I tried is incorrect.

Comment: `var x = [document.getElementById("div_name"),document.getElementById("div_name2")];`

Comment: You can also create a function that creates your list of divs on the fly by passing the id name into it, so that you don't have to repeat  'document.getElementById('id');  for every item in the list.

Comment: @JoseM sound really usefull! there is one problem, i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @OlivierGroeneveld no worries if you don't know..that's the beauty of it. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

So, If you just want them as a list of `div's` you could do this:

```
var x = [document.getElementById("div_name"),document.getElementById("div_name2")];
```

Just wrap them up with `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If your var should contain more than one object (div in your case), then you need to have more variable or, better, an array.

You can create yor array by using following code.

```
var x = [document.getElementById("div_name"), document.getElementById("div_name2")];
```

This is due to the fact that different DIVs in the DOM page are different objects...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such variable that is defined as:

```
var x = somthing, somesthingElse
```

You need to chose a variable that can store a collection of "things". In your case the Array is an ideal choice:

```
var x = [document.getElementById("div_name"),document.getElementById("div_name2")];
```

The brackets at the beginning and end of the expression are the syntax to declare a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `Array`, you can also store your `div`s in an `Object`

```
var divs = {
  div1: document.getElementById("div_name"),
  div2: document.getElementById("div_name2")
};
```

Thus, you could give a convenient name to your `div`s, but still pass them around as you please:

```
divs.div1;
divs.div2;
```

Or loop through them like so:

```
for (div in divs) {
  console.log(divs[div]);
};
```